# How does backpropagation differ from reverse-mode autodiff

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, backpropagation

Going through this [book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920052289.do), I am familiar with the following:

> For each training instance the backpropagation algorithm first makes a
>   prediction (forward pass), measures the error, then goes through each
>   layer in reverse to measure the error contribution from each
>   connection (reverse pass), and finally slightly tweaks the connection
>   weights to reduce the error.

However I am not sure how this differs from the reverse-mode autodiff implementation by TensorFlow. As far as I know the above algorithm first goes through the graph in the forward direction and then in the second pass computes all partial derivatives for the outputs with respect to the inputs. This is very similar to the propagation algorithm.

*How does backpropagation differ from reverse-mode autodiff ?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the above answer for the valid contribution however I have found the answer to this question by the author of the book himself:

> Bakpropagation refers to the whole process of training an artificial neural network using multiple backpropagation steps, each of which computes gradients and uses them to perform a Gradient Descent step. In contrast, reverse-mode auto diff is simply a technique used to compute gradients efficiently and it happens to be used by backpropagation.

Answer (score 0):

They are more or less specify the same thing. I think the difference is that back-propagation refers to the updating of weights with respect to their gradient to minimize a function; "back-propagating the gradients" is a typical term used.

Conversely, reverse-mode diff merely means calculating the gradient of a function. Nothing here in this process implies that we aim to the weights/values of a function.